# How to add new email to CNMutableContact in Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, cncontact

Quickly .. I have this code to add new contact , it was working until converting my code to Swift 3 , now it accept all properties except the email I get two errors :

> 1-Argument type 'String?' does not conform to expected type
>   'NSCopying'
>
> 2-Argument type 'String?' does not conform to expected type
>   'NSSecureCoding'

this is my code when I try to add email to contact :

```
    let workEmail = CNLabeledValue(label:"Work Email", value:emp.getEmail())
    contact.emailAddresses = [workEmail]
```

any help ?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In Swift 3, `CNLabeledValue` is declared as:

```
public class CNLabeledValue<ValueType : NSCopying, NSSecureCoding> : NSObject, NSCopying, NSSecureCoding {
    //...
}
```

You need to make Swift able to infer the `ValueType`, which conforms to `NSCopying` and `NSSecureCoding`.

Unfortunately, `String` or `String?` does not conform to neither of them.

And, Swift 3 removed some implicit type conversions, such as `String` to `NSString`, you need to cast it explicitly.

Please try this:

```
let workEmail = CNLabeledValue(label:"Work Email", value:(emp.getEmail() ?? "") as NSString)
contact.emailAddresses = [workEmail]
```

Or this:

```
if let email = emp.getEmail() {
    let workEmail = CNLabeledValue(label:"Work Email", value:email as NSString)
    contact.emailAddresses = [workEmail]
}
```

(Maybe the latter is the better, you should not make an empty entry.)

And one more, as suggested by Cesare, you'd better use predefined constants like `CNLabel...` for labels as far as possible:

```
if let email = emp.getEmail() {
    let workEmail = CNLabeledValue(label: CNLabelWork, value: email as NSString)
    contact.emailAddresses = [workEmail]
}
```

Comment: It's better to use `CNLabelWork` instead of "Work email" because the former is localized in every language

Comment: @Cesare, thanks. Nice suggestion. I'll take it in my answer.

Answer (score 8):

**Swift 3**: Email and Phone entry

**Documentation**: https://developer.apple.com/reference/contacts

```
let workPhoneEntry : String = "(408) 555-0126"
let workEmailEntry : String = "test@apple.com"
let workEmail = CNLabeledValue(label:CNLabelWork, value:workEmailEntry as NSString)
    contact.emailAddresses = [workEmail]

    contact.phoneNumbers = [CNLabeledValue(
        label:CNLabelPhoneNumberMain,
        value:CNPhoneNumber(stringValue:workPhoneEntry))]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 let workemail = "" //Your Input goes here
 let WorkEmail = CNLabeledValue(label:CNLabelWork, value: workmail as NSString)
 contact.emailAddresses = [WorkEmail]
```

For Swift 3

Comment: in the workemail  add input value And WorkEmail Add into contact.emailAddresses

Answer (score -1):

#### for Swift 3 and ios >= 9.0

You can use method CNContact mutableCopy

```
func saveVCardContacts (vCard : Data) {
    if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
        let contactStore = CNContactStore()
        do {
            let saveRequest = CNSaveRequest() 
            let contacts = try CNContactVCardSerialization.contacts(with: vCard)
            var mutablePerson: CNMutableContact
            for person in contacts{
                mutablePerson = person.mutableCopy() as! CNMutableContact
                saveRequest.add(mutablePerson, toContainerWithIdentifier: nil)
            }
            try contactStore.execute(saveRequest)
        } catch  {
            print("Unable to show the new contact")
        }
    }else{
        print("CNContact not supported.")
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. The OP's code creates a `CNLabeledValue` and he has a problem there. Your example does not address this problem in any way.

Comment: (FYI: I flagged this answer for deletion, as I've gotten the hint that cleanup is the new-new thing.)

Comment: @benc An incorrect answer is not a non-answer.

Comment: @matt - this code is orthogonal to the question. I don't know how familiar you are with `Contacts` Framework, but this answer is like: if I asked you how to add a work email to my personal card, this answer is analogous to: "if you are on macOS, open the Contacts.app".

Comment: @benc I agree 100%. So the question deserves a downvote. But it does not deserve deletion; it is not "not an answer". It _is_ an answer. It's just a _bad_ answer.

Comment: oh I though the flag was for the answer... the question is relevant, I think I read this one long ago when I was learning the framework.

Comment: You said you flagged the answer for deletion. If I were reviewing the queue, I would vote to keep this answer, not delete it. You can vote directly to delete it, right here; I'm just saying that flagging as "not an answer" would not, in my opinion, be correct.